# Obtener fecha de hoy con datepicker

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-datepicker

tengo un problema con colocar la fecha de ahora en el datepicker.

Lo que pasa es lo siguiente, tengo mi codigo de datepicker asi.

```
$.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
    closeText: 'Cerrar',
    prevText: 'Previo',
    nextText: 'Próximo',
    monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
    monthStatus: 'Ver otro mes',
    yearStatus: 'Ver otro año',
    dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sáb'],
    dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sa'],
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    firstDay: 0,
    initStatus: 'Selecciona la fecha',
    isRTL: false
};
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);

/* PRUEBA HOY DATEPICKER */


    $("#fecha").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    firstDay: 1
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());

//miDate : fecha de comienzo D=días | M=mes | Y=año
//maxDate: fecha tope D=días | M=mes | Y=año

 var unavailableDates = ["1-1-2019",    "19-4-2019",    "1-5-2019", "15-8-2019",    "12-10-2019",   "1-11-2019",    "6-12-2019",    "25-12-2019",];

    function unavailable(date) {
      dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
      if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
        return [true, ""];
      } else {
        return [false,"","Unavailable"];
      }
    }


    function setCustomDate(date) {
    var clazz = "";

    var arr2 = unavailable(date);
    var arr3 = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);

    return [(!arr2[0] || !arr3[0]) ? false : true, clazz];
    }
```

Y tengo estas variables para deshabilitar los fines de semana y que los dias que ya pasaron tambien esten deshabilitados en PHP

```
<?php
    if($comprarhoy==1) {
        if($dias[date("w")]=="domingo")
            echo  '$( "#fecha" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0,  beforeShowDay: setCustomDate  });';
        else if($dias[date("w")]=="sabado")
            echo  '$( "#fecha" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0,  beforeShowDay: setCustomDate  });';
        else if($dias[date("w")]=="viernes")
            echo  '$( "#fecha" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0,  beforeShowDay: setCustomDate  });';
        else
            echo  '$( "#fecha" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0,  beforeShowDay: setCustomDate  });';
    } else {
        if($dias[date("w")]=="domingo")
            echo  '$( "#fecha" ).datepicker({ minDate: +1,  beforeShowDay: setCustomDate  });';
        else if($dias[date("w")]=="sabado")
            echo  '$( "#fecha" ).datepicker({ minDate: +1,  beforeShowDay: setCustomDate  });';
        else if($dias[date("w")]=="viernes")
            echo  '$( "#fecha" ).datepicker({ minDate: +1,  beforeShowDay: setCustomDate  });';
        else
            echo  '$( "#fecha" ).datepicker({ minDate: +1,  beforeShowDay: setCustomDate  });';
    }
?>
```

Mi problema es que cuando yo entro a mi datepicker.

```
<input name="datepicker" type="text" class="date-pick" autocomplete="off" id="fecha" size="20" required="" style="color: transparent;text-shadow: 0 0 0 black;cursor:pointer;" />
```

Se muestra el dia de hoy, si esta bien, pero se me habilitan todos los dias, incluyendo los fines de semana.

[image: Fecha sin modificaciones]

Cuando deberia de mostrarse así.

[image: Fecha con modificaciones]

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solo necesitas usar `beforeShowDay` y `minDate` asi:

```js
$.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
    closeText: 'Cerrar',
    prevText: 'Previo',
    nextText: 'Próximo',
    monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
    monthStatus: 'Ver otro mes',
    yearStatus: 'Ver otro año',
    dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sáb'],
    dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sa'],
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    firstDay: 0,
    initStatus: 'Selecciona la fecha',
    isRTL: false
};
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);

var dateToday = new Date();
$("#fecha").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    minDate: dateToday,
    firstDay: 0
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<input id="fecha" >
```

Comment: Esta es la respuesta, muchas gracias !

Answer (score 0):

Eduardo. Me parece que ya existe una función dentro de datepicker que te permite hacer lo que necesitas:

```
$("#fecha").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    firstDay: 1
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Comment: Claro, el problema es el de abajo, se habilitan todos los dias, cuando deberia de deshabilitar los fines de semana y los dias que ya pasaron, ese es mi dilema.